# Any alternatives to principal component analysis

Tags: machine-learning, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I was wondering if there are any alternatives to PCA (Principal Components Analysis) for the purpose of feature reduction.

Specifically, I am thinking of a feature reduction algorithm other than PCA for image recognition applications. Any Idea?

Comment: Does this link answer your question? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection

Comment: Sure, on this site, see questions tagged [tag:dimensionality-reduction] and/or [tag:feature-selection]!

Comment: I don't think this is too broad, as the OP only wants a list. And the comments already seem to provide that

Comment: If you go for neural network then I  can suggest deep `Auto Encoder`.

Comment: If you go for neural network then I  can suggest deep `Auto Encoder` because it's non-linear function.  Rather than auto encoder you con try `t-SNE`, `Genetic Algorithm` or `LDA`. Regarding `LDA` some author says it's a classifier and someone says it can be used as feature reduction.

Answer (score 1):

If you go for neural network then I  can suggest deep `Auto Encoder` because it's non-linear function.  Rather than auto encoder you con try `t-SNE`, `Genetic Algorithm` or `LDA`. Regarding `LDA` some author says it's a classifier and someone says it can be used as feature reduction.

```
PCA
Auto Encoder 
Genetic Algorithm
Ensembler
t-SNE(Stochastic Neighbour Embedding)
LDA*

*LDA => Linear Classifier / Dimension reduction technology
```

Comment: LDA as a linear classifier is actually a merging of Fischer's Linear Discriminant (a bit of matrix math + a matrix inversion via numerical SVD solver) and some sort of classification algorithm appropriate for linearly separable clusters.  Fischer's Linear Discriminant is the Linear Discriminant; "Analysis" seems to mean something up to classification for some, and lower level for others.